# how to disable future date and time also from datetimepicker js

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I could able to stop future dates as `.datetimepicker({maxDate: new Date()}`

Is there any function for Time also?

Comment: Link to the js file you're using? there are many datetimepickers

Comment: @Raju akula - did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @catalyst, No but I validated from backend programing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, if you are using the Bootstrap DateTimePicker from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  :

```
function ValidateDateTimePicker() {
    var eventTime = $("#dateTimePickerField").data('DateTimePicker').date();
    var currentTime = new Date();

    if (eventTime > currentTime) {
        alert("error")
    }       
}
```